# Como ignorar un import y simular clases utilizando Jest

Tags: javascript, test, jest, jestjs

Tengo una clase y una funcionalidad para agregar una clase de citas, en el momento que trato de realizar un unit testing con Jest a la función de agregarCita(cita) de la clase Citas me arroja un error que no llego a comprenderlo.
Estuve leyendo por la documentación de Jest y lo que encontré es algo como de simular la función de una función valga la redundancia, sin embargo, no entendí ni madres y hay un spanglish muy hardcore por lo que me complica más.
Es problema se da en el momento que agrego el import ui, de otra manera... si quito tanto el import y la instancia del mismo, si puedo ejecutar el código, pero mi intención no es esa, sino comprender el ejercicio y aunque puede que sea una mala práctica instanciar una clase dentro de otra clase, lo que quiero saber es como utilizar Jest es este tipo de casos.

Si alguno me colabora con esto se lo agradezco.

**Funcionalidad de la clase ctias.**
[image: Funcionalidad de la clase citas.]

**Testing jest de la clase citas**
[image: Testing jest de la clase citas]

**Error en consola de testing citas**
[image: Error en consola de testing citas]

Comment: Las imágenes no compilan, si pones el código como texto podemos intentar copiar y pegar para dar una respuesta. Además, las imágenes se ven demasiado pequeñas en un dispositivo móvil. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida y para conocer la importancia de un [mcve]

Comment: Sube la clase `administrador-citas.js` por favor. No se logra ver cómo instancias la clase `Citas`.